# I'm having trouble setting the value of a variable that will update my test

Tags: java, testing, automation, automated-tests

My problem is in the part where I'm doing the "if/else" conditions, when I call the function that will perform the comparisons and will define if the test passed or not and will send some information, I'm receiving null.
Problems are among the asterisks. If anyone can help me

This is my code :

```
   public static void fxSpot_GBP_JPY(TradeData data, TradeData output) throws Exception {
        if (data == null) {
            fail("The input data object was not correctly filled");
        }
        if (output == null) {
            fail("The output data object was not correctly filled");
        }
        
        //Used to set the comment, the status and update to JIRA
        FieldsJSON fields = new FieldsJSON();
        String assertionError = "";
        
        List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        String newDate = Utils.formatTimeZoneMinute(data.getTradeDate());
        String asOfTrade = Utils.formatTimeZoneMinute(data.getAsOfTradeDate());
        String executionDate = Utils.formatTimeZoneMinute(output.getExecutionDateTime());

        try {            
            //Add the data in the list
            inputs.add(data.getTransactionNumber()); outputs.add(output.getBloombergId());
            inputs.add(newDate); outputs.add(output.getTradeDate());
            inputs.add(asOfTrade); outputs.add(executionDate);
            inputs.add(data.getSettlementDate()); outputs.add(output.getValueDate());
            inputs.add(data.getTradeAmount()); outputs.add(output.getAmount2());
            inputs.add(data.getCustomerAccountCounterparty()); outputs.add(output.getMiPartyId());
            inputs.add(data.getPrincipalLoanAmount()); outputs.add(output.getAmount());
            inputs.add(data.getSecurityPrice()); outputs.add(output.getRate());
            inputs.add(data.getISOCodeOf1stCurrency()); outputs.add("BRL");//output.getCurrency2()
            inputs.add(data.getISOCodeOf2ndCurrency()); outputs.add(output.getCurrency1());

            //Compare values
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            int y = 0;
            int x = 0;
            
            for(String input : inputs) {        
                for(String out : outputs) {
                    if(y == x) {
                        if(input.equals(out)) {
                            WriterCSV.setOk("Ok");
                            **String comment = input + " = " + out;
                            fields.setComment(comment);
                            fields.setStatus("PASS");**
                            System.out.println("ok - " + input + " = " + out);
                        }else {
                            WriterCSV.setOk("not Ok");
                            **String comment = input + " = " + out;
                            fields.setComment(comment);
                            fields.setStatus("FAIL");**
                            System.out.println("not Ok - " + input + " = " + out);
                        }
                    }
                    x = x+1; // count of the list of output 
                }
                y = y+1; // count of the list of inputs
                x = 0; // reset to 0 the count of outputs
                
            }
            // evidence with the name and value of fields compared
            WriterCSV.reportSpot_CSV(data,output);
          }
```

Here is my test:

```
@Test
    @Tag("compare")
    public void CompareSpot() throws Exception {
        //Create a list to read the CSVfile
        List<DTOTradeData> dto;
        
        //Used to get the TradeData of list dto.
        DTOTradeData dtd = new DTOTradeData();
        
        // Read a csvFile and return a list with the values to new xml
        dto = CSVReader.readCSV("spot.csv");
        
        //The xpath of xml
        FileDriverSpot spot = new FileDriverSpot();
        FileDriver output = new FileDriverSpotOutput();
        
        FieldsJSON fields = new FieldsJSON();
        
        //new xml = dataInput and the outputFile = dataOutput
        TradeData dataInput = new TradeData();
        TradeData dataOutput = new TradeData();

        for (int i = 0; i < dto.size(); i++) {
            dtd = dto.get(i); // get TradeData
            dtd.getTradeData().setDriver(spot); // set the driver 

            if (fileExist(Setup.xmlPath + dtd.getInputFile() + ".xml")) {
                
                dataInput = Reader.read(spot, Setup.xmlPath + dtd.getInputFile() + ".xml");
                dataOutput = Reader.read(output, Setup.spotPath + dtd.getOutputFile()); 

                try {
                // make the comparison  
                **FunctionalTest.fxSpot_GBP_JPY(dataInput, dataOutput);**
                }
                catch(AssertionError e) {
                    String comment = e.toString();
                    fields.setComment(comment);
                    
                }
            } else {
                fail("The file: " + dtd.getTemplateFile()
                        + " needs to go through the writing process before being compared.");
            }
                        
//Convert the file to base64
String inputData = UpdateTestStatus.convertToBase64(Setup.xmlPath + dtd.getInputFile() + ".xml");
    String outputData = UpdateTestStatus.convertToBase64(Setup.spotPath + dtd.getOutputFile());
    String evidenceCompared = UpdateTestStatus.convertToBase64(Setup.reportPath+"ReportSpot.csv");
             
            System.out.println(UpdateTestStatus.updateTestRun(**fields.getStatus(),fields.getComment()**,
                inputData,dtd.getInputFile()+ ".xml", //data of the XML and the name of the file
                    outputData,dtd.getOutputFile(),
                    evidenceCompared,"ReportSpot.csv",
                    Setup.testExec, dtd.getJiraId()).asString()); // ID testExecution and ID of 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the definition of `FieldsJSON`?

Comment: Sorry, FieldsJson is the class where the getter and setter methods are responsible for updating some fields (status, comment, assignee and evidences). I'm using jackson library to build the JSON structure that will be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test and the code under test each create a separate instance of `FieldsJSON`. Data set in one instance will not be visible in the other (unless the data is declared `static`, in which case there's no need to create instances).

You can fix this by using a single instance, either passed to the `fxSpot_GBP_JPY` method from the test, or returned from that method to the test.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Moore for your answer you really helped me.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Would you mind accepting the answer?